# UI built using xib is messed up

Tags: ios, user-interface, xib

I created a UI for landscape view of my application. It is perfectly designed, all is aligned well in my xib. However, when I run my application in simulator, everything is out of order in the design. Everything is not in it's default position in xib. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you applied auto layout constraints or have you applied auto resizing at least to all your view components ???

Comment: Use auto layout is unchecked. And yes, it has auto resizing on its components

Comment: Hmmmm are you sure auto resizing is applied perfectly ?? You have any prior experience with auto resizing ?? I personally recommend consider using auto layout it is simple to understand and very much reliable

Comment: I'm not sure about it. How about if I disable all auto rezising? Will all components go into their allocated place?

Comment: it won't buddy :) when you drag view components on to view and don't apply auto layout constraint or autoresizing constraints on it your UI system has no idea where and how to render them :D ex : assume you designed your view using xib with the size matching iPhone 4s now you run on iPhone 6 plus sizes are different so it will simply start rendering from top margin and will screw up your UI :)

Comment: I see. So I think I should learn how auto resizing works first

Comment: Better learn auto layout constraints :D autoresizing is yesterdays technique :) move on buddy :)

Comment: Actually, its an existing code. And I just need to improve it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125472/discussion-between-drbj-and-sandeep-bhandari).